# Server Essentials 2016 MEMORY.DMP file well over 100 gigs

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Essentials Server 2016 serving as a Hyper-V host, Domain Controller, and File Server. It has a MEMORY.DMP file that consistantly grows to well over 100 gigs. I would like help exploring why that is happening. If the file is deleted, it just rebuilds and grows back to over 100 gigs within days of the deletion. I installed WhoCrashed Pro and it only detects one crash within the file: DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is (usually) caused by bluescreens writing a memory-dump. The server is stable and not crashing, as are the VMs?

Comment: Is it possible for the MEMORY.DMP file to be that big while only containing the one memory dump? The server is pretty stable. It freezes every once in a while, but it isn't blue screening.

Comment: How much RAM does the server have?

Comment: The server has 128 gigs of RAM